# Extrude and Bevel a group of characters with some in front of others and the front characters occluding those behind

Tags: adobe-illustrator, 3d

How might I take a character sequence such as "ABC" and achieve a 3D effect with A in front of and partially occluding B, and B in front of and partially occluding C. I also want to make each letter a different color.

Comment: What have you tried? Where is that failing?

Answer (score 1):

Type one letter, set the fill to the colour you want, apply the 3D effect you want. Copy and paste twice to duplicate, so you now have 3 letters. Edit the letters, recolour, and move into position as you require. Move up or down the stack using Object > Arrange

An example using the Inflate effect

[image]

Comment: Thank you. For the "one in front of the other" part, is there any way of having auto alignment make the same distance effect between each letter? Is there a way of treating the 3 characters as one object, so that if I wanted to rotate them or twist them, or whatever, I could do the same thing to all 3 simultaneously?

Comment: @PortMadeleineCrumpet Not sure if that would work to be honest. The letters are all slightly different shapes, and I think you'd need to balance their placement by eye, until it looks right.  Sorry,  no, any further rotation would need to be done manually on each letter. These are individual objects, each with their own independent 3D effect. Anything more complex would probably need to be done using an actual 3D application, such as Blender.  Illustrator is fairly limited in this respect.